# guard-livereload on Windows

Tags: windows, guard, livereload

My config of guard-livereload on **Windows**:

- RubyInstaller 1.9.3-p429
- DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559
- gem install: guard guard-livereload wdm
- newest browser extension for Firefox 2.0.9.xpi

I don't have any problems in console:[image: :] (maybe except that guard tells me that I'm using old gem json (I've installed latest 1.8.0) but also tells me that Browser connected or disconnected.

The problem is, that sometimes guard-livereload (mostly) doesn't refresh page or refreshing it only once. The Guardfile is the same I'm using on Linux Fedora, where it's working with similiar config... :-/

Did anyone use guard-livereload successfuly on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

A didn't find explanation for this issue, but I found replacement of LiveReload - [LiveReloadX](http://nitoyon.github.io/livereloadx/) which works :)